# Unicode display error with vscode + latex workshop on macOS

Tags: pdftex, mactex, vscode

I'm new to using latex in VScode with latex workshop extension.

Before writing my thesis with the [IEEE template](http://ras.papercept.net/conferences/support/tex.php) (`ieeeconf.zip`), I followed this excellent [tutorial](https://mathjiajia.github.io/vscode-and-latex/) to configure my related settings. However, I met lots of Unicode errors that I couldn't build the `root.tex` file in the `ieeeconf.zip`. Here is the screenshot of the part of Unicode errors:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the encoding is Western (Mac Roman):

[image]

Two steps:

1. Reopen with Encoding "Western (Mac Roman)"
2. Save with Encoding "UTF-8"

Then compile the file `root.tex`.